# simple HTML validator

Tags: html, c++

I have a homework problem which asks me to write a simple HTML validator which checks for matching start and end tags.

Here is my code and input file below.

```
void removeSpaces(std::string &str){ 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) 
        if (str[i] != ' ') 
            str[count++] = str[i];
    str[count] = '\0'; 
}

bool isHtmlMatched(std::vector<std::string>& htmlTags){
    std::stack<std::string> temp;
    typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator Iter;
    for (int i = 0; i < htmlTags.size(); i++){
        if (htmlTags[i][1] != '/')
            temp.push(htmlTags[i]);
        else{
            if (temp.empty()) return false;
            std::string open = temp.top().substr(1);
            std::string close = htmlTags[i].substr(2);
            std::cout << open << " " << close <<std::endl;
            if (open != close){
                std::cout << "Failed at where " << temp.top() << " didnt match with " << htmlTags[i] << std::endl;
                return false;
            }
            else{
                temp.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    if(temp.empty()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << " These start tags ";
        while(!temp.empty()){
            std::cout << temp.top() << " ";
            temp.pop();
        }
        std::cout << "do not have a matching end tag " <<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> htmlTags;
    std::string input_line;
    std::ifstream file("Validhtml.txt");
    std::string tag;

    int line = 0;
    while(std::getline(file, input_line)){
        int pointer = 0;
        int position_start = input_line.find("<",pointer);
        while (position_start != std::string::npos){
            if(input_line.find(">", position_start + 1) == std::string::npos){
                std::cout << "INVALID HTML" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "ERROR ON LINE " << line + 1 << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }
            int position_end = input_line.find(">", position_start + 1);
            tag = input_line.substr(position_start, position_end - position_start + 1);
            removeSpaces(tag);
            htmlTags.push_back(tag);
            pointer = position_end + 1;
            position_start = input_line.find("<", pointer);
        }
        line++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < htmlTags.size(); i++){
        std::cout << htmlTags[i] << std::endl;
    }

    if(!isHtmlMatched(htmlTags)){
        std::cout << "INVALID HTML" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "VALID HTML" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
<html><
head></head><body>    My HTML page 


 <p></p> <h2>Hello world! </ h2>
<ol><li> #myfiles</li>
</ol>
</body >

</html>
```

I currently have two problem with this code.

1. I don't know how to read tags that are split in different lines, for example the `<head>` tag at the end of the first and start of the second line of the input file.
2. Even after I removed all the white space, this program still won't recognize `<h2>` and `</ h2>` are a matching tag. Same issue goes for `<body>` and `</body >`

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: You should learn how to step line by line through your code with a debugger.

Comment: I think base problem is you work with lines - you should work with characters instead- it would be too complicated to manage elements on multiple lines in your current version...

Comment: html doesn't allow whitespace between `<` or `</` and the tag name: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags

Comment: reading line by line is probably not the correct approach, you'd  normally read a character at a time and use some form of state machine to parse out each tag

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this for a bit and got something I think should work for you.

Here's how the code works: First, we open the html file and push it all into a string with no whitespace. Next, we send that string to a function to detect tags. Once a tag is detected, we try to see if its an opening or closing tag. We then save the tag to the correct container (either the `opening_tags` container or the `closing_tags` container). Finally, we run a series of tests on the two containers we have. (1) Are they the same size? (2) Are they empty (meaning no tags were detected)? (3) Do all tags in the `opening_tags` container correspond to a tag in the `closing_tags` container.

If all three of our tests are passed, then we can say the html file is valid (based on tag matching).

For the containers, I used hashsets (known as `std::unordered_set` in C++). This is because hashsets are really fast in inserting and removing elements. In your specific instance, the order of the tags shouldn't matter. However, keep in mind that, in an actual validator, it would matter greatly.

If you have any more questions on my code, feel free to ask! Without any more waiting, here's the code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

// Gets rid of all file white space and returns the string
std::string condense(std::ifstream&);

// Tests if all tags are matching and returns if they are
// (true) or if they aren't (false)
bool validate(const std::string&);

int main()
{
    std::ifstream html_stream("input.html");
    const std::string html_string = condense(html_stream);
    const bool html_valid = validate(html_string);

    // Prints the html string (mostly for debugging)
    std::cout << html_string << '\n' << std::endl;

    if (html_valid)
        std::cout << "Valid HTML!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Invalid HTML..." << std::endl;
}

std::string condense(std::ifstream& stream)
{
    std::string file_no_whitespace;

    if (stream.is_open())
    {
        std::string cur_token;
        while (stream >> cur_token)
            file_no_whitespace += cur_token;
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "File is not open!" << std::endl;

    return file_no_whitespace;
}

bool validate(const std::string& data)
{
    // These should be the same size if the html is valid
    // (based only on tag matching)
    std::unordered_set<std::string> opening_tags, closing_tags;

    // For tags like '<br />'
    std::unordered_set<std::string> self_closing_tags;

    // Keeps track of the current tag to push into either
    // opening_tags or closing_tags
    bool tagging_open;

    // Process each character to make tags
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        const auto* cur_char = &data.at(i);

        if (*cur_char == '<')
        {
            std::string cur_tag;

            if (*(cur_char + 1) == '/')
            { // Test for closing tag
                tagging_open = false;
                i++;
                cur_char++;
            }
            else // Tag is an opening tag
                tagging_open = true;

            i++;
            cur_char++;
            while (*cur_char != '>') // Until tag closes
            {
                cur_tag += *cur_char;
                i++;
                cur_char++;
            }

            // Test for self-closing tag
            if (*(cur_char - 1) == '/')
                self_closing_tags.insert(cur_tag);
            // Not self-closing, so it's a normal type of tag
            else if (tagging_open)
                opening_tags.insert(cur_tag);
            else if (!tagging_open)
                closing_tags.insert(cur_tag);
        }
    }

    // If the hashsets aren't the same size, then we automatically know
    // there is at least one unmatched tag
    if (opening_tags.size() != closing_tags.size())
        return false;

    // If the hashsets are both empty, then we know there are no tags
    if (opening_tags.empty())
        return false;

    // If both above tests have been passed, we now need to make sure that
    // every opening tag has a matching closing tag
    std::vector<bool> tag_match(opening_tags.size(), false);
    size_t tag_match_pos = 0;
    for (const auto& tag : opening_tags)
    {
        auto closing_tag_itr = closing_tags.find(tag);
        if (closing_tag_itr != std::end(closing_tags))
        {
            tag_match.at(tag_match_pos) = true;
            tag_match_pos++;

            // Remove match tag to avoid duplicates causing false-positives
            closing_tags.erase(closing_tag_itr);
        }
    }
    bool all_matched = true;
    for (const auto& match : tag_match)
    { // Make sure all values in the 'tag_match' vector are true
        if (!match)
        {
            all_matched = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return all_matched;
}
```

Comment: _the order of the tags doesn't matter._ In XML (XHTML), elements must be correctly nested. A `std::stack` (as adapter to a `std::deque` or `std::vector`) appears more appropriate to me than a `std::unordered_map`. The stack would make detection of incorrect nesting very easy. AFAIK, HTML (if not XHTML) doesn't require that all opening tags have a corresponding closing tag. An element is closed automatically with its parent element (or even a sibling with same tag ID).